# Upgrading 15.04 to latest release 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, 15.04

Trying to upgrade to 16.04.

Tried following [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)  as best as I can, but soon ran into trouble by getting lots of 404 errors when I tried to replace the repositories with old-repositories (GUI Method).

Also Vivid seems to not be listed in the old-repositories directory http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/, which seems to me to be the issue, why would it now be listed?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As pointed to in my description, this link is not helping me, as I believe that vivid is not listed at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/.

Comment: @MrMule So don't replace the repository data for Vivid with oldreleases, yet.  It should then still otherwise work.  Problem then is you'll have to go check the file manually to make sure it's not on oldreleases.  (As of this post, Vivid is still on the standard archive page, likely because older Phone OS versions for Ubuntu Phone may still be using Vivid repos).